# memcpy_s and strcpy_s error but manual for loop works

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, memcpy, strcpy

In my example, strcpy_s and malloc_s throw an error while manual copying seems to work. here's the code. This works:

```
hookaddrinfoluacode=(char *)malloc(16384);
// This works           
for(i=0;i<strlen(this_token);++i){
   hookaddrinfoluacode[i]=this_token[i];
}                       
hookaddrinfoluacode[i+1]='\0';
```

This doesn't

```
memcpy_s(hookaddrinfoluacode,sizeof(char),this_token,strlen(this_token));
```

And neither does this:

```
strcpy_s(hookaddrinfoluacode,strlen(this_token),this_token);
```

The error seems to be thrown from this code line in standard library:

```
 _VALIDATE_RETURN_ERRCODE(dst != NULL, EINVAL);
```

this_token is obtained from `this_token=strtok_s(NULL,":",&next_token);` call.

I'm confused :)

Comment: Do the standard library functions work properly?

Comment: You have an [Obi-Wan](http://catb.org/jargon/html/O/obi-wan-error.html).

Comment: From the code that throw error, it seems your destination pointer become null in some way, will you check it?

Answer (score 2):

`memcpy_s` throws an exception if the source won't fit in destination. `sizeof(char)` is 1.  Both also validate pointers are not NULL, so you must have one.

Answer (score 0):

The error you see seems to be validating that the destination pointer received is not null. Are you allocating it before using it? As you showed you are doing manually? Apart from that you should give the size of the destination buffer as the second parameter and the number of bytes you want to copy in the fourth. It should be like this:

```
hookaddrinfoluacode=(char *)malloc(16384);
memcpy_s(hookaddrinfoluacode, 16384 * sizeof(char),this_token,strlen(this_token) );
```